# How to yield element multiple times

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to implement a method, in which each element of list gets yielded as much as the paramter says:

```
def rgen (n):
    for elem in list:
        yield elem
```

When I call rgen(2), I would like to yield every element of that list twice etc.
But how could I actually implement that?

Comment: don't forget to pass `list` as an argument to the function. and probably call it something other than `list`, say, `inlist`, as list is a built-in type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Loop again:

```
def rgen (n):
    for elem in list:
        for times in xrange(n):
            yield elem
```

I'd probably write a helper function similar to:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def repeated(iterable, n=1):
    items = chain.from_iterable(repeat(item, n) for item in iterable)
    for item in items:
        yield item

    # Or, in Python3.3 you could do:
    yield from items
```